# adding reciepeints for mail in java mail api program

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have created the method in class named A as shown below which functionality is to send the mails using java mail api , now the bellow method accepts the parameters now my query is that how should i add recipients in an array as the recipients must be of array type that is passes please advise

```
class A 
{
public boolean postMail(String recipients[], String subject, String message, String from) throws Exception {
        boolean debug = true;
        boolean result = false;

        // create a message
        try {
            // set the from and to address
            InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);
            this.mimeMessage.setFrom(addressFrom);
            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[recipients.length];
            for (int index = 0; index < recipients.length; index++) {
                addressTo[index] = new InternetAddress(recipients[index]);
            }
            this.mimeMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, addressTo);
            this.mimeMessage.addHeader("MyHeaderName", "myHeaderValue");

            // Setting the Subject and Content Type
            this.mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
            this.mimeMessage.setContent(message, "text/html");
            Transport.send(this.mimeMessage);
            result = true;
        } catch (MessagingException messagingException) {
            result = false;
            messagingException.printStackTrace();
            // throw new CASSException(messagingException);
        }
        return result;

    }
    }

now my query is that i am trying to invoke this method from within the class shown below '


    class A 
    {


    String Subject  = "testmailsubject";
    String message = "simple test message";
    String from ="test@abc.com";


    A a1 = new A ();
    a1.postMail



    //***********method *************
    public boolean postMail(String recipients[], String subject, String message, String from) throws Exception {
        boolean debug = true;
        boolean result = false;

        // create a message
        try {
            // set the from and to address
            InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);
            this.mimeMessage.setFrom(addressFrom);
            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[recipients.length];
            for (int index = 0; index < recipients.length; index++) {
                addressTo[index] = new InternetAddress(recipients[index]);
            }
            this.mimeMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, addressTo);
            this.mimeMessage.addHeader("MyHeaderName", "myHeaderValue");

            // Setting the Subject and Content Type
            this.mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
            this.mimeMessage.setContent(message, "text/html");
            Transport.send(this.mimeMessage);
            result = true;
        } catch (MessagingException messagingException) {
            result = false;
            messagingException.printStackTrace();
            // throw new CASSException(messagingException);
        }
        return result;

    }


    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to initialize an array ?

Answer (score 0):

Add Receipeints like this

```
Address[] TO = new Address[] {InternetAddress.parse("karthik@cherukuri.com"),
                                   InternetAddress.parse("karthik2@cherukuri.com"), 
                                   InternetAddress.parse("karthik3@cherukuri.com")}; 
message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, TO);
```

else if you want to send recipient array directly to method just initialize it email list you wanted.

```
String Subject  = "testmailsubject";
String message = "simple test message";
String from ="test@abc.com";
String[] recipient = new String[]{"karthik@cherukuri.com","karthik2@cherukuri.com", "karthik3@cherukuri.com"};
a1.postmail(recipient,subject,from,message);
```